# Java data structure design for data of different types represented by timescale

Tags: java, oop

I'm trying to suss out object oriented design and have come across an issue I'm finding weird, and I'm not sure of a good strategy to structure my data.

The API I'm accessing provides data as follows:

```
<pair_name> = pair name
    a = ask array(<price>, <whole lot volume>, <lot volume>),
    b = bid array(<price>, <whole lot volume>, <lot volume>),
    c = last trade closed array(<price>, <lot volume>),
    v = volume array(<today>, <last 24 hours>),
    p = volume weighted average price array(<today>, <last 24 hours>),
    t = number of trades array(<today>, <last 24 hours>),
    l = low array(<today>, <last 24 hours>),
    h = high array(<today>, <last 24 hours>),
    o = today's opening price
```

source: https://www.kraken.com/help/api#get-tradable-pairs

The bit I'm having trouble working out how to handle are the `array(<today>, <last 24 hours>)` bits. I'd like to have a structure that conformed to this that each fits into. I'd separate them out in to Volume, TotalTrades and HighLow objects (or something like that) but the type for today/last 24 hours varies (sometimes `int` sometimes `double`).

I thought I'd try either this:

```
public abstract class DayTimeFrameData {
    protected Object today;
    protected Object lastTwentyFourHours;
}
```

or something like this:

```
public interface DayTimeFrameData {
    Object today = null;
    Object lastTwentyFourHours = null;
}
```

Then extending/implementing one of those for each data type. But I'm not sure that these make any sense at all.

Can someone offer me some pointers for how to go about structuring something like this, please?

Comment: What you're describing is not an API, it's a set of data. The API would be driven by the data users. IOW, for OO design you need to consider how the data is going to be used.

Comment: Ha, ok I didn't make that distinction. The title of the page I got it from was "API: Learn about our API". In terms of how I could use it, I might want a button that would switch all the data between today and last 24 hours. I've got no problem over engineering it, this is more for my understanding of OOP.

Comment: Aha! Then the first thing that comes to mind is something along the line of `interface AccumulatedData` and `interface AccumulaedDataSource { AccumulatedData getDataFor(PeriodType period);}`. Then build you view around `AccumulatedData`

Comment: Do you have a reference for what you mean? I'd like to read up, you've lost me a bit there, and what I'm googling for clarification isn't making sense.

Comment: I invited you to the chat, let's sort it out there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interface specifies methods but not fields, so you can't use that approach. You could use something like this:

```
public class DayTimeFrameData {
    protected double today;
    protected double lastTwentyFourHours;
}
```

since a double can also represent an integer. Then simply use objects of this type as fields.

```
public class PairInfo {
    protected DayTimeFrameData volume;
    protected DayTimeFrameData numberOfTrades;
    protected DayTimeFrameData low;
}
```

However, if each of these needs its own specific methods, you may indeed make DayTimeFrameData abstract and extend it for each type. For example:

```
public class NumberOfTrades extends DayTimeFrameData {
    /* methods and fields specific to NumberOfTrades */
}
```

If you'd like to restrict the types of the fields to specifically Double or Integer for specific implementations, you could use generics:

```
public abstract class DayTimeFrameData<T extends Number, L extends Number> {
    protected T today;
    protected L lastTwentyFourHours;
}
```

An implementation can then specify which types are allowed.

```
public class NumberOfTrades extends DayTimeFrameData<Integer, Double> {
    /* methods and fields specific to NumberOfTrades */
}
```

The above would state that the `today` value is an Integer, and the `lastTwentyFourHours` value is a Double. If they both always need to be the same type, you can get by with one type parameter on DayTimeFrameData. Note that we do need to use the wrapper types (Double, Integer) instead of the primitive types (double, int) in this case.

Comment: Perfect the last abstract with variable types is exactly what I'm looking for, thanks so much.

Comment: I'm I right in thinking, to find out more I'd need to look up generics?

Comment: @Sarcoma Indeed. Check the Java tutorials on the subject: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/ And also look around for related questions here.